# I want to change z-index value of navbar when bootstrap modal is active

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have below bootstrap modal and I below navbar.I want to change z-index value of navbar when the bootstrap modal is active because header shows over modal.I cant see modal because of navbar.How can I do it?

```
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-whatever="@mdo" id="deneme1" style="z-index: 2147483647;"><i class="fa fa-edit text-thm2"></i> Sign Up</a>
                            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

---

```
  <div  id="sticky-header-navbar">
            <!-- nav -->
            <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
                <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- /nav -->

        <style>
            .sticky-header-navbar {
                position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
                position: sticky;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 2147483647;
            }
        </style>
```

---

bootstrap version:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
```

Comment: The easiest way is to set the modal's z-index to something really high, like 999.

Comment: You also don't need to set the z-index of your header that high. Just make sure the modal is at least one greater than it, and you'll be good to go. :)

Comment: @JoelHager First, I think like you, so I reduced z-index of navbar but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you post your code in a workable snippet/fiddle so we can inspect it?